How to handle dot-sourcing in Pester v5?
I would like to test this code with Pester, but without creating a .psm1 and without creating an extra .ps1.
# file GetSomething.ps1
function Get-Something # this is testable with pester
{
  'something'
}
# Some-Other-Function or call that takes very long or can't be run in Pester.
Do-Something-Expensive-NotTestable
Get-Something

The corresponding test according to Pester Docs:
#file GetSomething.Tests.ps1
BeforeAll {
  . $PSScriptRoot\GetSomething.ps1
}

Describe 'Get-Something' {
  It 'Gets something' {
      Get-Something | Should -Be 'something'
  }
}

I found various articles online describing my issue in detail. For example https://jakubjares.com/2015/01/10/test-script-end-to-end/ is a very detailed explanation why you want to dot-source and why it is an issue with Pester. It lists possible solutions with pros and cons, but it is from 2015.
The best solution I could find was this post. The new BeforeAll looks like this:
BeforeAll {
  function Get-Functions($filePath)
  {
      $script = Get-Command $filePath
      return $script.ScriptBlock.AST.FindAll({ $args[0] -is [Management.Automation.Language.FunctionDefinitionAst] }, $false)
  }

  Get-Functions GetSomething.ps1 | Invoke-Expression
}

I would imagine that almost everyone using Pester has this issue. Is there any newer/better approach to fix this with Pester v5? I do prefer .psm1 modules mostly, but sometimes I prefer script and functions in a single file and still want to test the functions in an extra file.

The approach outlined in the top works fine for me. but there is een error in your pester script: RuntimeException: Legacy Should syntax (without dashes) is not supported in Pester 5. Please refer to migration guide at: https://pester.dev/docs/migrations/v3-to-v4. Meaning: us the parameter: -Be

"I would imagine that almost everyone using Pester has this issue." - I still don't understand what the issue is? Your original example (dot-sourcing the .ps1 script file) works just fine. Are you getting an error when invoking the test suite?

@MathiasR.Jessen There is a much detailed explanation in my first mentioned link. Imagine inside GetSomething.ps1 is a call that breaks code, stops or just takes long if called from pester. I don't always want to execute all code GetSomething.ps1 when I just want to test GetSomething function. Does that help? I will enhance my example on the top a bit.

@iRon thanks for mentioning. I hopefully fixed the code now.

"without creating an extra .ps1" this makes it an XY problem, if the concerned function isn't just a simple helper function but heavy ennough to  be pester tested on itself, I would take it aside, either long term (and dot-source it from the main script) or short term (by putting it back in once it is considered fully pestered and stable).

That's certainly opinion-based, but I would love a testing tool that helps me testing anything from the language. I do not know why Powershell offers this in the first place, but it does and I need a way to isolate functions without splitting into multiple files (sometimes).
